# A long HTTP request will pause the websocket data transfer?

Tags: http, websocket

I have a page PA witch contains an iframe element, and the src attribute of the iframe reference to page PB. In PA, I've established a websocket connection with the server.

So, in this case, if I have a large file to post to server in PB, will this operation pause the data transfer between the PA and server?

I mean, the post request in PB will take more than 1 minute to finish, is that means in this 1 minute, all the data transfer will be paused in a queue, until the post request is finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each websocket uses a dedicated connection to the server. Any other browsing activities, like an upload in another iframe, shouldn't affect them much. The connection quality might suffer a bit due to network congestion, but data exchange should still be possible.

That means unless the web browser has a maximum number of connections or connections per server and websocket connections are also counted for that limit. But then I would rather expect the upload to fail, because it's the later operation.